# JavaScript live graph axis labels not displaying as they should

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am attempting to create a live chart in JavaScript. I gathered data from a webpage using web scraping. The scraped data, along with the respective timestamps is stored in a CSV file.  I wrote JavaScript code for the chart, featuring a linear graph with both long and short values. The y-axis ranges from 0 to 100, while I aim to display the last 24 scraped data points on the x-axis. The graph should be updated every hour, providing a representation of the past 24 hours. However, a problem arises when I attempt to use the time of the update as the x-axis labels for the chart. I am trying to retrieve this data from the CSV file, but it doesn't  work for some reason.When i open the page graph is not visible and i get this error in console in dev tools:

```
chart.js:19 Uncaught Error: This method is not implemented: Check that a complete date adapter is provided.
at Ln (chart.js:19:103166)
at En.formats (chart.js:19:103384)
at No.init (chart.js:19:153179)
at chart.js:19:92557
at u (chart.js:13:1237)
at An.buildOrUpdateScales (chart.js:19:92282)
at An._updateScales (chart.js:19:95016)
at An.update (chart.js:19:94179)
at An.<anonymous> (chart.js:19:90551)
at An._doResize (chart.js:13:5520
```

```
function fetchData() {
        console.log('Fetching data...');
        fetch('/get_data')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log('Received data:', data);
                updateChart(data);
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));
    }
    function updateChart(data) {
        console.log('Chart Data (Before Update):', myChart.data);

        // Calculate the time difference from the last timestamp in the chart
        const lastTimestamp = myChart.data.labels.length > 0 ? myChart.data.labels[myChart.data.labels.length - 1] : null;
        const currentTime = new Date(data.timestamp);
        const lastTime = lastTimestamp ? new Date(lastTimestamp) : null;

        // Add new data to datasets
        myChart.data.labels.push(data.timestamp); // Assuming each update adds a new label
        myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(data.short);
        myChart.data.datasets[1].data.push(data.long);

        // Remove the first element if you want to keep a fixed number of data points (e.g., 24 hours)
        if (myChart.data.labels.length > 24) {
            myChart.data.labels.shift();
            myChart.data.datasets[0].data.shift();
            myChart.data.datasets[1].data.shift();
        }
        myChart.update();

        console.log('Chart Data (After Update):', myChart.data);
    }
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: [],  // Initialize as an empty array
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Short Line',
                    data: [],
                    borderColor: 'red',
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    fill: false
                },
                {
                    label: 'Long Line',
                    data: [],
                    borderColor: 'green',
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    fill: false
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
                x: {
                    type: 'time',  // Use 'time' type for x-axis
                    position: 'bottom',
                    time: {
                        unit: 'minute'  // You can adjust the time unit based on your preference
                    }
                },
                y: {
                    max: 100,
                    min: 0,
                    stepSize: 10
                }
            }
        }
    });

    setInterval(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, 10 * 1000);  // 1 hour in milliseconds
```

Comment: If one of your axis is a time cartesian axis, you have to include in your project a time adapter, [see the docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#date-adapters). [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/m1rzbt9o/)'s a simple CDN project that includes the `luxon` adapter, which means that it includes both [`luxon-adapter`](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-luxon) and the [`luxon` package](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) itself. You may choose any of the [available adapters](https://github.com/chartjs/awesome?tab=readme-ov-file#adapters)